# Separate TabularInline format page in Django Admin Panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I was implementing Tabularinline in my code,

**Admin.py**

```
class EmpEducationInline(admin.TabularInline):
      model = EmpEducation
      extra = 1
      min_num = 1
      max_num = 10

class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ('get_serial_number', 'employee_id', 'name', 'department_name',
                'design', 'doj', 'salary', 'display_img', 'edit_emp', 'delete_emp')
     list_per_page = 25
     search_fields = ('emp_id', 'name')
     inlines = [EmpEducationInline]

admin.site.register(Employees, EmployeeAdmin)

class EmpEducationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('emp_id', 'degree', 'depart', 'institution', 'year')
    list_filter = ('emp_id', 'degree', 'depart', 'institution') 

admin.site.register(EmpEducation, EmpEducationAdmin)
```

**my output**

[EmployeeAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVkCB.png)

[EmpEducation Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agjtm.png)

Here Tabular inline Format was showing in Employee Admin Page, But I want Separate TabularInline Format in EmpEducation Admin based on My model. I want to Enter education related details separately in another model. Becaz I want to implement the concept of bulk creation here.

In Employee Education form look,

employee Id was in Dropdown remaining details below like image

[Employee Education Separate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqsCK.png)

Here below I shared my **models.py** code

```
class EmpEducation(models.Model):
    emp_id = models.ForeignKey(
        'Employees', models.PROTECT, db_column='emp_id')
    degree = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    depart = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    institution = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    year = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'emp_education'
```

*Thanks in advance...*